# How can I covert my csv file to xts in R?

Tags: r, csv, converters, xts

My csv file looks like this, HOW CAN I CONVERT THIS TO A XTS Object ?
[CSV FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh42S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(xts)
z <- read.csv("CSV_FILE", header = TRUE, sep =",")
x <- xts(z[,-1],order.by=as.Date(z$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Replace CSV_FILE with your filename and location.